# .NET Core MVC Page Not Refreshing After Changes

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.2

I'm building a .NET Core MVC on the latest version 2.2. I have a problem when I make changes to the CSHTML file and refresh the page, my changes are not reflected in the browser. I have to restart the project in order to see my changes. This has been happening for a while now so I'm not exactly sure what change caused this issue.

I've tried using the chrome's "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" as well as other browsers to no avail. This happens on Windows and Mac using both Visual Studio for Mac and VS Code

In a default .Net Core project it works fine so it must be something in my project that changed along the way. I'm wondering where I need to start in order to debug this issue? I've tried commenting out almost everything in my `Startup.cs`and `Program.cs` with no resolution.

Comment: I'm encountering the same MissingMethodException you mentioned below... Did you ever figure it out? If, so could you please answer your question?

Comment: For use with Rider and/or Razor Class Libraries (RCL), [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58289831/107625).

Comment: Wow. Didn't see that coming. A real bummer. After 2 years this is upvoted only 147 times. Makes you wonder who's building apps with .NET Core...

Comment: Make 100% sure you are actually looking at the right area of code.  I wasted many hours on this stupid issue only to find out it really was updating my code.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

There was a change made in ASP.NET Core 2.2 it seems (and I can't find any announcements about this change). If you are not explicitly running in the 'Development' environment then the Razor Views are compiled and you will not see any changes made to the .cshtml

You can however turn off this using some config in your Startup class as follows.

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options => options.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange = true);
```

For ASP.NET Core 3.0 and higher, see Alexander Christov's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637903).

Comment: Thank you. However, it appears that when I enable this, make a change in the html, and then refresh, I get the following exception:

```MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Cci.IMethodReference Microsoft.Cci.ICustomAttribute.Constructor(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitContext)'.
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbol.Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.ISymbol.GetAttributes()```

Any idea on what this exception means? All of the other pages load fine. Only when I edit a file and refresh do I get this error

Comment: This worked for me. To set it depending on environment, add IHostingEnvironment to the Startup method and persist in a property. Then use something like `services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options => options.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange = _env.IsEnvironment("MyEnvironment"));`

Comment: thanks it worked. However I think it's pretty awkward and silly that Microsoft doesn't officially announce big changes like this.

Comment: @kevskree same thing is happening to me

Comment: This is not working for asp.net core version 3.1 . Please suggest for 3.1

Comment: @Mayank Gupta: see Alexander Christov's answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637903/198990). His answer worked for me (3.1).

Comment: this worked, but weird that this is project specific, and have to add the package each time we create a new project. I thought that there would be any ide tweak or some property change before finding this solution.

Answer (score 447):

In **ASP.NET Core 3.0 and higher**, `RazorViewEngineOptions.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange` is not available.

Surprised that refreshing a view while the app is running did not work, I discovered the following solution:

1. Add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) NuGet package to the
   project
2. Add the following in `Startup.cs`:

   ```
   services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
   ```

Here's the [full explanation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#runtime-compilation) for the curious.

Comment: This didn't work for me for whatever reason. I'm on Mac if that makes a difference.

Comment: @Nakul what is .net core version you use?

Comment: When I used this command: ls /usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/ I seemingly got two answers: 2.1.13 and 3.0.0

Comment: @Nakul this is what you have installed, which one is your app's .net core version?

Comment: Awesome! Totally works for me on ASP.NET Core 3.0. I ended up with the following line:
`services.AddMvc().AddControllersAsServices().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);`

Comment: This worked great for me on Mac and ASP.NET Core 3.1.

Comment: <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version="3.1.2" />

services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

Comment: Thx for this hint; worked for me on .Net Core 3.1.2

Comment: Thanks for the hint and for the link to the article on MSDN! I've followed the [conditionally enable runtime compilation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.0#conditionally-enable-runtime-compilation) part of it and it worked well. Judging by the time it takes now to recompile a fairly simple view, I would highly recommend this way instead of enabling it always.

Comment: Wowsers! 15 years working in .NET and it used to be easy. 1 day working with .NET Core and everything seems broken.  
And seriously - who decided it was a good idea to make HTML compiled and not changeable at runtime by default, then make developers hunt for a solution?

Comment: I get this error message - Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 6.0.0-preview.4.21253.5 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1

Comment: Looks like Startup.cs is the place to go for everything in .Net Core :)

Comment: Worked for me on .NET 5

Comment: Thanks ! Working on Windows Visual Studio 2019 Versión 16.11.3 and .net core 3.1.1

Comment: Wored for me on .Net 5 with VS 2019 16.11.5 - What a pain!

Comment: This one has 20 prerequisites Packages OMG

Comment: services.AddMvc(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false).AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();   -- this worked for me in Startup.cs.  The ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES entry in launchSettings.json didn't do anything.   FWIW can't seem to get Hot Reload to work either.   in .Net 6.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I spent too many hours debugging and trying different solutions since we upgraded our project from 2.x to 3.1 and the views stopped working.

Comment: with .net 6 on VS2022 this also works great!

Comment: .NET 7 on VS 2022 works

Comment: The "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" NuGet package targets .NET. You'll need it to match your application's target framework. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Matching the version did for me too
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation" Version 6.0.19, NET6 and VS2022

Comment: When installed, it fails with "namespace name 'IConfiguration' could not be found". Same error with injected IWebHostEnvironment.
When uninstalled, the error goes away

Comment: @JBress This indicates that IConfiguration is not registered with your DI container. In earlier versions of .net this was the case. In .net 5 and above IConfiguration is registered with the DI container which indicates a version mismatch. Have you checked this?

Answer (score 72):

I've just created a new project using the latest ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 template and I altered the following to get runtime recompilation enabled for Debug:

Reference NuGet package - **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation**.

Startup.cs - ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) WAS:

```
// stuff...

services.AddControllersWithViews();

// more stuff...
```

NOW:

```
// stuff...

var mvcBuilder = services.AddControllersWithViews();

#if DEBUG
    mvcBuilder.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
#endif

// more stuff...
```

Comment: This is the best answer without reading the article posted by Alex, which is worth the read.

Answer (score 50):

In addition to [Alexander Christov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57637903/2501279), since ASP.NET Core 3.1 you can enable the view compilation for development environment [without changes to the `Startup` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#conditionally-enable-runtime-compilation-in-an-existing-project):

1. Install the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` NuGet package.
2. Set next environment variables (for example via environmentVariables section in launchSettings.json):

   - `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to "Development".
   - `ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES` to "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; it allows for the desired functionality without needing to alter the Startup file.

Comment: And if you upgrade a project from .NET 5 to .NET 6, you will need to update `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` from v5.x to v6.x as well or you won't be able to see changes in Razor Views or Pages as you make them.

Comment: Hello... I am having this same problem but it did not work. The bad side effect is that all accented vowels appear ugly in the browser. If I remove `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` from launchSettings.json file, accented vowels appear correct again. It seems there is no solution to the view compilation problem.

Answer (score 21):

first of all install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation using nuget manager
after that add below code into your startup.cs

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

net6.0 also this works.

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Answer (score 14):

For those using Net core 3.0 or greater

1. Go to Tools → Nuget package manager → Manage nuget pakages for solution
2. move to browse tab to browse from internet
3. search for RuntimeCompilation
   Click on Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation
4. install it on your intended projects the current stable version
5. open Startup.cs file
6. go to void method ConfigureServices
7. add line:   `services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`
8. you are DONE

Rerun and see. Now you can refresh your views or pages.

Answer (score 13):

You should just add this:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

to the `ConfigureService()` method.

Be aware below code is not available in ASP.NET Core 3.1:

```cs
services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
```

Comment: You need to install nuget package to get it working  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Runtime

Answer (score 5):

Using .net core 2.2 running app with command [`dotnet watch run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch?view=aspnetcore-2.2) the project is restarted after every change

Answer (score 5):

Below helped me when views were in separate project.

```
if(HostingEnvironment.IsDevelopment()){ // only in development (optional)
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(o => {
        o.FileProviders.Add(new PhysicalFileProvider(PATH_TO_PROJECT));
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me when working with Razor Class Libraries. Cheers!

Comment: Using Core 3.1 followed these directions, installed version 3.1.16 and received error: 'IMVcBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddRazorRuntimeCompilation' and no extension method 'AddRazorRuntimeCompilation' accepting a first argument of type 'IMVcBuilder' could be found.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue while working on a .NET 6 MVC Web App.

I installed **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Runtime.Compilation** from NuGet Package Manger then added `.AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` after

```
builder.services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

so that it looks like this

`builder.services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();`

and it worked!

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem in Rider by adding the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to resolve this issue:

**1**. Check the permissions of folder in which your .sln file present.There may be a problem with file access permissions as Visual studio may not be to access files when IIS express server is running, so to reflect new .cshtml changes each time you need to restart the server,so I suggest edit the folder access permissions by:

**Right click on folder->properties->security->click on edit button -> check all options->save**.

Restart Visual studio to see changes.

*If this does not work then use 2 option.*

**2**.In your project in **startup.cs** file add this below line **ConfigureServices()** in  method :

> **services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options => options.AllowRecompilingViewsOnFileChange = true);**

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022 Preview, it seems there is an option called Hot Reload for this purpose.

[image]

It seems to be available in Visual Studio 2019 too.

> With Hot Reload you can now modify your apps managed source code while
> the application is running, without the need to manually pause or hit
> a breakpoint. Simply make a supported change while your app is running
> and in our new Visual Studio experience use the “apply code changes”
> button to apply your edits.

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/

Comment: Enabling hot reload after each file save occurs is great option in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` nuget installed, but it was version 5.x.x.  Updating to 6.x.x resulted in the pages properly updating when changed.  So make sure you update!

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely sure you are using 2.2? Check your csproj because it might be this bug https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/issues/2466
You could try turning off `RazorCompileOnBuild` more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/sdk?view=aspnetcore-2.1#properties

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem upgrading from .net Core 3 to .net 5.0

Problem was due to old dependency in Telerik controls that we could not change.

Fixed by changing references in the .csproj file

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" Version="3.8.0" />
```

to

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis" Version="3.8.0" />
```

(your version may be different)

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and after trying few of the above suggested options (including the one marked as answer) without success.

So, I decided to trash `Startup.cs` and build the `Program.cs` properly. Then my **`Hot Reload`** started working.

Answer (score 0):

For me (.NetCore 8 in VS2022)

1. Add [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation/) NuGet package to the project
2. Enabling hot reload after each file save

[image]

Then evey time you `CTRL + S`, VS will rebuild the project and auto refresh the browser