# How do I troubleshoot auto-refresh failing silently in ASP.NET Core 5?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-5, asp.net-core-5.0

I read about the [Auto-refresh capability introduced in ASP.NET Core 5 with .NET 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-5.0?view=aspnetcore-5.0#auto-refresh-with-dotnet-watch).  I upgraded my Blazor site to .NET 5, and thought it would just work, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

I used to use Westwind.AspNetCore.LiveReload, but I have removed it to try this out.

When I make a change, the app rebuilds and restarts web server for me, but the browser doesn't refresh. This is a project I upgraded from .NET Core 3.1. Is there anything that needs to be done in startup.cs to enable this? What else could be interfering? How can I troubleshoot?

Answer (score -1):

You can livereload page using methods mentioned in that question answers
[.NET Core MVC Page Not Refreshing After Changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639969/net-core-mvc-page-not-refreshing-after-changes)

Comment: I was hoping to use the built-in functionality and avoid Westwind, as I noted in my question.

Comment: check this may help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639969/net-core-mvc-page-not-refreshing-after-changes

Comment: The revision and link don't apply to the new auto-refresh capability just released in ASP.NET Core 5, part of .NET 5. For what it's worth, I already have .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation() on. Thanks for trying, though.