# Razor Pages only render when using RuntimeCompilation .NET 8 Preview 6

Tags: c#, razor-pages, runtime-compilation, .net-8.0

I experience some strange behaviour. When using the standard ASP .NET 8 (or .NET 7) Web App template, the template does not render (or the route is not recognized) unless I use RuntimeCompilation - and I don't want to.

In the browser I'm presented with the standard 404 error page in Chrome.

The middleware pipeline seems fine

```
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);    
// Working
// -----------------------------------------------
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

// Not Working
// -----------------------------------------------
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

I'm using .NET 8 preview 6

Comment: Can you please provide some [mre] with routes tried which return 404 when should not?

Comment: It applies when I create a new web app using the template in visual studio 2022 17.6.5
I can only view i.e. https://localhost:7060/index if I use RunTime compilation.

I wonder if there is some kind of setting in VS I have missed.

Comment: I have investigated the issue further. It only applies when building and running the project from VS 2022. If I build and run the project from PowerShell everything is fine.

Comment: Was not able to repro. Have you installed and run the project from latest preview version (for .NET 8)?

Comment: Also you can try modifying the `launchSettings.json` and adding `ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES` environment variable with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` value there.

Comment: Yes, I working on the latest preview version, and I happens also on a clean project template. I'm suspect is must be some kind of local setting in VS2022

Comment: Do you have the latest VS preview too?

Comment: Thx. This did the trick!!. I was using VS2022 17.6.5

Comment: Was glad to help! Added last two comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was not able to repro but as workaround you can try modifing `launchSettings.json` by adding `ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES` environment variable with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` for corresponding run profile (a bit more info about this can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65438390/2501279)).

Also be sure to use the latest VS 2022 preview version (17.7 Preview 4 ATM) to work with the latest .NET 8 preview.