# ASP.NET Core "Start without debugging" won't make changes

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm new to ASP.NET Core, I'm using 6.0, but my "Start without debugging" is in trouble somehow.

I know that when I use the "ctrl F5", the web starts and I can make changes while it is running, but when I tried to change the cshtml files, it just won't change what is on the web, even when I refresh the web.

Changes only happen when I close and rerun it or after I edit the files, save, and press "ctrl alt enter" in Visual Studio.

I tried installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation` and added `builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();` to the `Program.cs` but it seems like it doesn't help

Comment: Maybe that post can help you with your problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639969/net-core-mvc-page-not-refreshing-after-changes?rq=2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested ASP.NET Core and installed Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation ,it works
Try it :

1. Install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation NuGet package.
2. In Program.cs, add"builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();"